# Javascript Scale image and Transfom image position veritcally, horizontally

Tags: javascript, css

I want to transform the image vertically, horizontally and also scale the image using javascript. At the moment I manage to get the resize image to work but it doesn't look right. I am trying to have something similar to  [Transform image](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/transform/). when the move vertical bar is adjusted the image should move up and down and when the move horizontal is adjusted the image should move horizontally. At the moment the testresize() function is working with resizing the image but it doesn't look like what I want. I want to apply a CSS transform property containing translateX(), translateY() and scale() transforms to each of the image. [Range Slider](https://jsfiddle.net/suabiut/yrxuvt53/)

```html
<div id="toggle-components">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Choose image to display</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="mage1" onclick="if(this.checked){displayimg()}")><label for="image1">diving</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="mage2" onclick="if(this.checked){displaybgimage()}")><label for="image2">jumping</label>
                     
                </div>

<div id="container">
 <img id="dolphin1" class="image" src="../images/img/image1.png" >
            <img id="dolphin2" class="image" src="../images/img/image2.png" >
            
        </div>
```

```html
<div id="adjust-components">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Adjust image</legend>

                        <label for="vertical-control">move vertical:</label>
                        <input id="vertical-control" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0"><br>

                        <label for="size-control">resizesize:</label>
                        <input id="size-control" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" onChange="testresize(this.value)"><br>

                        <label for="horizontal-control">move horizontal:</label>
                        <input id="horizontal-control" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0"><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

```js
var gettestimage=document.getElementsByClassName("image");
//resize image
function testresize(val){

    for(var i=0;i<gettestimage.length;i++){

        var chek1 = document.getElementById("image1");
        var chek2 = document.getElementById("image2");
      
        if(chek1.checked){
            gettestimage[0].style.width=5*(val / 1)+'px';
            console.log(val)

        }else if(chek2.checked){
            gettestimage[1].style.width=5*(val / 1)+'px';

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the `transform` css property then why are you setting `width` and `height` to scale the image? The solution is actually quite simple, I just had to to use the `tansform` property instead. This solution only works with a single image but I am sure you can manage to make it work with multiple.

```js
var image = document.getElementById("image1")

//The transformation (scale, translation, rotation) of the image
var transform = {
  translation: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  scale: 1
};

function scaleImage(val){
  transform.scale = val;
  applyStyle()
}

function translateImage(axis, val){
  transform.translation[axis] = val;
  applyStyle()
}

function applyStyle() {
  image.style.transform = `scale(${transform.scale}) translate(${transform.translation.x}px, ${transform.translation.y}px)`
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="image1" class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" width="500">
</div>
        
<div id="adjust-components">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Adjust image</legend>
    <label for="vertical-control">move vertical:</label>
    <input id="vertical-control" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" onchange="translateImage('y', this.value)"><br>
    <label for="size-control">scale:</label>
    <input id="size-control" type="range" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="0.1" onchange="scaleImage(this.value)"><br>
    <label for="horizontal-control">move horizontal:</label>
    <input id="horizontal-control" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" onchange="translateImage('x', this.value)"><br>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```